# How to filter array in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, sorting

I have array

```
 const arr = [
    {id: 1, country: 'Austria'},
    {id: 2, country: 'Germany'},
    {id: 3, country: 'Austria'},
  ];
```

I tried the following the code to filter it.

```
arry.map((item,idx) => (
   item.country== "Austria"?(
       console.log(item.id)
   )
   :
   null
))
```

The output is

> 1 3

,
but I want to get output after whole filter like

> 1,3

I want only the IDs where country is Austria as given below.

> 1,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `reduce` function

```js
const arry = [
    {id: 1, country: 'Austria'},
    {id: 2, country: 'Germany'},
    {id: 3, country: 'Austria'},
  ];
  
   const result = arry.reduce((acc,item,idx) => {
    
          if(item.country == "Austria"){
             if(idx === 0) acc += item.id
             else acc += `,${item.id}`
           }
           
           return acc
      
    }, '')
    
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is How I Filter

```
const arry = [
    {id: 1, country: 'Austria'},
    {id: 2, country: 'Germany'},
    {id: 3, country: 'Austria'},
];

const result = arry.filter((item, index) => {

      if(item.country == "Austria"){
         return true
       }
       
       else{
        return false
       }
  
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line answer:

```
arr.filter(i => i.country == 'Austria')
```

Answer (score 0):

onChange={(e)=>{setSearch(e.target.value)}}

users.filter(item=>item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())).map((item)=>